# Fixed position interfering with scrolling on site

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am creating a website, but when i try to scroll, the page stays fixed. I can see the scroll bar moving up and down but the page isn't moving. I changed the screen height and width but it didn't change anything. The only way the page actually scrolls the way it is supposed to is when I change the different sections I have on my page from "fixed" position to relative. When I change it to relative though, the entire screen gets distorted and everything gets out of place. My code basically consists of different sections, which are all in the fixed position(I am sure that the position is the problem) and inside the sections, I have text and images(all fixed position). How do I fix this?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <title> Home|Cloudberrie</title>
<style>
    #top{
background-color:#E7E5DF;
height:3rem;
width:100%;
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
z-index: -1;


}
#logo{
background-color:white;
height:3.5rem;
width:100%;
position:fixed;
z-index:-1;
top:48px;
left:0;


}
#banner{
background-color:white;
height:7rem;
width:100%;
position:fixed;
z-index:-1;
top:100px;
left:0;



}


.button{

    border:none;
    background-color:#1f88ca;
padding: 20px 40px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius:18px;
  width:200px;
  position:fixed;
  top:400px;
  left:100px;
  color:white;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
 

}
button:hover{
background-color:red;
}
#choose{
background-color:white;
height:30rem;
width:100%;
position:fixed;
z-index:-1;
top:550px;
left:0;

}

html { 

height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 overflow:auto;
padding-bottom:2000px; 
} 

</style>    
</head>
<body >
    <section id ="top">
<p style="position:fixed; right:1800px;bottom:880px;"><i class="fa fa-location-arrow" aria-hidden="true"></i>    Plano, Texas</p>
    <p style="position:fixed; right:1650px;bottom:880px;"><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i>   (123) 456 7890</p>
    <p style="position:fixed; right:1460px;bottom:880px;"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>    support@gmail.com</p>
    </section> 
    <section id="logo">
<img src="berrylogo.png"height="25"width="25" style="position:fixed;left:10px;top:56px;">
<img src="cloudberie.png"height="30"width="150" style="position:fixed;left:40px;top:56px;">
<p style="position:fixed; right:350px;top:65px;"><a href="file:///C:/HTML/cloudberry.html">Home</a></p>
<p style="position:fixed; right:275px;top:65px;"><a href="file:///C:/HTML/cloudberry.html">About</a></p>
<p style="position:fixed; right:180px;top:65px;"><a href="file:///C:/HTML/cloudberry.html">Services</a></p>
<p style="position:fixed; right:110px;top:65px;"><a href="file:///C:/HTML/cloudberry.html">Client</a></p>

</section>
<section id ="banner">
<img src="banner-3.png"width="100%" height="450px">
<h1 style="font-family:sans-serif;color:#1f88ca;position:fixed; top:180px;left:100px;">MAIN TEXT</h1>
<p style="font-family:sans-serif;color:grey;position:fixed; top:250px;left:100px; font-size:40px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur </p><br><p style="font-family:sans-serif;color:grey;position:fixed; top:290px;left:100px; font-size:40px;">adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</p>
<button class="button">Learn More</button>

    </section>
<section id="choose">
<p style="font-size:2.5rem;color:#5e5e5e;position:fixed;top:630px;text-align:center;left:760px;"> <b>WHY CHOOSE US</b></p>
<div style="width:80px;height:3px;border:1px; background-color:#25ace4;position:fixed;top:700px;left:890px;"></div>

<img src="why-us-pic.jpg"width="300px;"style="position:fixed;top:800px;left:425px;">
<p style="font-size:1rem;position:fixed;top:800px;left:800px;">At consectetur lorem donec massa sapien faucibus et molestie ac. Molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum. Faucibus pulvinar elementum integer enim. Eu consequat ac felis donec et odio. Ac ut consequat semper viverra nam libero justo laoreet sit. Condimentum vitae sapien pellentesque habitant morbi.</p>



</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you add the code, so we can help?

Comment: If you are talking about `screen.height` and `screen.width` then changing them has no effect on the page.

Comment: I just added the code. @Latecoder

Comment: Im not talking about screen.height or screen.width, I think the problem has to do with the position of the elements on the page

Comment: concerning your last edit, please read 
[**How should we treat posts that are vandalized by their original authors?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/106812/251777)
Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on Stack Overflow, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the CC BY-SA 4.0 license for Stack Overflow to distribute that content. By Stack Overflow 

policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed elements do not move on page scroll. That is why they were made. So to fix it, do not set `position` to `fixed`. Here is `position:fixed` defined by MDN:

> The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout. It is positioned relative to the initial containing block established by the viewport, except when one of its ancestors has a transform, perspective, or filter property set to something other than none (see the CSS Transforms Spec), in which case that ancestor behaves as the containing block. (Note that there are browser inconsistencies with perspective and filter contributing to containing block formation.) Its final position is determined by the values of top, right, bottom, and left.

Here is an example of `position:fixed`:

```js
for(let i=0;i<100;i++){
 document.body.innerHTML+="<p>normal positioning</p>"
}
```

```css
#fixed{
 position:fixed;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="fixed">fixed text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the small amount of detail I have, I think what you are looking for is absolute instead of fixed. That being said, manual positioning of elements is generally not good practice. If this doesn't work try adding more information like code snippets and screenshots

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, when I change the code from fixed to absolute, only some elements in the page move. I edited my post to include my code.